# Sort the list and insert a new column in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to sort states and figure out the highest temperature for each state in this weather data residing in mongodb.

How do I iterate through each record in Javascript and insert a new column 'month_highest' when I figure out the highest temperature for that state ?

---

```
Day Time    State   Airport Temperature Humidity WindSpeed
1   54  Vermont BTV 39  57  6
1   154 Vermont BTV 39  57  4
1   254 Vermont BTV 39  57  5
1   354 Vermont BTV 38  70  5
1   454 Vermont BTV 34  92  11
```

16  53  Florida ORL 46  71  9
16  153 Florida ORL 47  71  8
16  253 Florida ORL 46  73  8
16  353 Florida ORL 47  74  8
16  453 Florida ORL 46  79  7
16  553 Florida ORL 46  79  5
16  653 Florida ORL 46  83  4

Comment: What have you tried? There aren't record or columns in MongoDb. Where would you insert the value?

Comment: I'd suggest you look at using the aggregation framework. Lots of good examples here that are similar in complexity here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-examples/

Comment: I recommend using Aggregation as well. MongoDB Map-Reduce is single-threaded and very slow.

Answer (score 0):

### [MongoDB Map-Reduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/)

```
db.temps.mapReduce(
    /* map */
    function() {
        emit( this.State, this.Temperature);
    },

    /* reduce */
    function key(key, values) {
        var ret = 0;
        for (var i=0; i<values.length, i++) {
            if (values[i] > ret) ret = values[i];
        }
        return ret
    },

    /* params */
    {
         query: { 
             DateTime: { 
                 $gte: new Date('2013-01-01')
                 ,$lt: new Date('2013-02-01') 
             }
         }

         ,sort: {
             State:1
         }
    }
);
```

As for inserting a new month-max, that depends on how you want to store it?  How are you querying this data?

You *could* output the results into a new collection, or use that programmatically to update another collection.  It depends on how you want your data shaped.  It actually looks like you are really flat with your data as it stands.

Comment: I was thinking we can sort first by state, then by temperature. Then you can iterate through the documents and know that whenever the state changes you have reached the highest temperature for that state. The resulting output should have "month_high" inserted.
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("520bea012ab230549e749cff"),
    "Day" : 1,
    "Time" : 54,
    "State" : "Vermont",
    "Airport" : "BTV",
    "Temperature" : 39,
    "Humidity" : 57,
    "Wind Speed" : 6,
    "month_high" : true
}